# How to capture shinyalert input field as variable

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

I'm trying to use the relatively new `shinyAlert` package to see if it offers better results than the `sweetalert` package but I'm unable to figure out how to get this:

```
Myvar <-  shinyalert input text
```

from this minimal example.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinyalert)

ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  useShinyalert(),
     actionButton("run", "Run", class = "btn-success")
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  shinyEnv <- environment()

  observeEvent(input$run, {

    shinyalert('hello', type='input')
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

My thanks for any help from you geniouses out there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how you do it:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyalert)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyalert(),
  actionButton("run", "Run", class = "btn-success")
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$run, {
    shinyalert('hello', type='input', callbackR = mycallback)
  })

  mycallback <- function(value) {
    cat(value)
  }
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

It's done using callbacks. You can assign the value to a reactive variable if you'd like.

I had fully documented the package last month and was about to release it, and then my computer crashed before I had a chance to push to github, and lost all progress. I haven't had a chance to work on it again. So sorry that the documentation isn't great yet, the package is still un-released so use at your own risk for now :)

(Notice that you don't need shinyjs for this)

Comment: Fair enough, but this does not save the value to variable... What if you need to condition on the output of the shinyalert? For instance, I would need it to return a boolean variable - how do I store it to a variable?

Comment: The documentation for shinyalert shows one way to do this, shinyalert automatically saves the response inside `input$shinyalert`. Or you can use the code in my answer together with a `reactiveVal()` variable.

Comment: Just want to say thanks for all your hard work on this, Dean. It's really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I have no experience with the package shinyalert, but you can achieve what you want with the widely used and well documented modal dialogs from shiny. Maybe you there is a reason for you to stick with shinyalert that I am unaware off, but if not, example code for achieving what you want with modal dialogs:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  actionButton("run", "Run", class = "btn-success"),
  textOutput("output1")
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  dataModal <- function(failed = FALSE) {
    modalDialog(
      textInput("input1", "Enter text:",
                placeholder = 'Enter text here'
      )
    )
  }

  # Show modal when button is clicked.
  observeEvent(input$run, {
    showModal(dataModal())
  })

  output$output1 <- renderText({
    input$input1
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Without testing yes this might work but won't be what I'm looking for.  For one reason because my app already uses dozens of sweet/shiny alerts and I would like to stick to the same style

Comment: Ok, sounds reasonable. I hope someone else with more experience with the shinyalert package can help you.

Comment: I had a look at the github repository https://github.com/daattali/shinyalert/blob/master/inst/www/srcjs/shinyalert.js but I'm not sure how to figure out the callback functions